# Python threading with timer - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to make a small function that does some fetching in the background for my application, so I want my application to continue normal execution after calling this (so this should be non-blocking). I want this to run on a scheduled thread every X seconds.
To do so I have the following:

```
    def start(self): 
        sync_thread = threading.Timer(30, self.readMessages(self.queue, self.client))
        sync_thread.start()
```

where `queue` and `client` are initialized in the `__init__` function and assigned to `self`.
The first start for the thread and invocation to my `readMessages` function works well, though currently after 30 seconds I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1254, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any idea what to do with it, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to pass a callback function to `threading.Timer`. Instead you currently call the function once immediately and pass its return value, that's probably not what you want. Try a lambda instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` because the `threading.Timer` routine is trying to call the function you passed, however, as @CherryDT mentionned in the comments, you didn't pass any function, rather you passed the return value of the `readMessage` method in your class.

What you need to do instead is:

```py
def MinPrinter:
    def __init__(self, xs):
        self.xs = xs
    
    def callback(self, xs): # This is your 'readMessages' function
        print(min(xs))
   
    def start(self, n):
        t = threading.Timer(n, self.callback, args=(self.xs,))
        t.start()


mp = MinPrinter([1, 2, 0, 3, -1])
mp.start(30)

# Will print after 30 seconds
-1
```

Arguments need to be specified with the `args` parameter. Optionnaly, you can also pass keyword arguments using the `kwargs` parameter (need to pass a dictionnary).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def start(self): 
    sync_thread = threading.Timer(30, self.readMessages, args=(self.queue, 
    self.client))
    sync_thread.start()
```

you should pass a callable object to `timer` and when you use `self.readMessages(self.queue, self.client)` you are executing the function and not passing it.

and anyway using Timer will not give you what you want. it will call the function `self.readMessages` once after 30 seconds but it will not repeat every 30 seconds.

a (very) simple way of doing it

```
from threading import Thread 
from sched import scheduler
import time

class SchedTask(Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, task, task_args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self.scd = scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self.interval = interval
        self.task = task
        self.task_args = task_args
    
    def schedual_task(self):
        self.scd.enter(self.interval, 1, self.schedual_task)
        self.task(self.task_args)
        self.scd.run()

    def run(self):
        self.schedual_task()
```

Then in you code you can use it like that

```
def t(*args):
    print("i am a task")

st = SchedTask(5,t)
st.start()
#rest of your code
...
```

there are many ways of doing this but this is just a simple example.